# flutter easy_localization 3.0.2 - default language at boot

Tags: flutter, flutter-easy-localization

I've this app with flutter 3.0 and easy_localization 3.0.2 package.
I want to set a default language at boot of the app.
I use *startLocale: Locale('ru', 'RU')* but it seem not function.
It use the language that is set in the *context* in the previous execution of the app.
How can i solve this problem?

````
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

import 'generated/locale_keys.g.dart';
import 'lang_view.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', 'US'),
      Locale('ar', 'DZ'),
      Locale('de', 'DE'),
      Locale('ru', 'RU'),
      Locale('it', 'IT')
    ],
    startLocale: Locale('ru', 'RU'),
    path: 'resources/langs',
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(title: 'Easy localization'),
        // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
        '/second': (context) => const SecondPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

to use startLocale you need to set saveLocale: false otherwise it will not work by default saveLocale is true , so you  need to set saveLocale:false.